# Meteor Leaderboard Example JS Pattern Explanation

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

In the Meteor Leaderboard example, there is the following line of Javascript code:

```
Session.equals("selectedPlayer", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
```

I know this is shorthand JavaScript, I believe for some sort of 'if' statement, but I can't remember exactly how it works. I was wondering if someone could provide an explanation of what exactly is going on here. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var x = conditionExpression ? trueExpression : falseExpression

// The above is equivalent to the one below.

if(conditionExpression){
    var x = trueExpression
}else{
    var x = falseExpression
}
```